# "system-ui" CSS font-family in Chrome doesn't recognize font-weight above certain font sizes on macOS

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, fonts

I recently bought a new 2019 iMac, 27-inch screen with the Retina 5K display. It was meant to replace my older late-2013 model which has been my workhorse for a long time.

[image]

Shortly after getting up and running with Chrome, I noticed that certain headings on websites were bolder than I remembered, and was able to figure out that it was happening with websites which used a variation of the system font stack. Specifically, if `font-family` was set to `BlinkMacSystemFont` or `system-ui`, headings were often no longer rendered with the correct font weight. Everything appears as if font weight was set to `normal`.

What's weirder is that through some fiddling around in dev tools ([Codepen link](https://codepen.io/Aias/pen/ExVKyOO)) I've figured out that this only happens with font sizes at or above 20px, so there's some kind of size dependency which affects the issue. It also seems to have something to do with font smoothing, as font-weight starts working again if I set `-webkit-font-smoothing: none;`, but then it looks absolutely terrible. See below for a screenshot of what I mean.

[image]

I'm completely baffled by this. I've tried installing San Francisco from [Apple Developer resources](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/). I've gone to Font Book -> File -> Restore Standard Fonts, which didn't work. I've also tried both checking and unchecking 'Use font smoothing when available' in Settings -> General.

If I open up Chrome's dev tools and go to Computer -> Rendered Fonts, it says `.SF NS`, which I assume means it's finding San Francisco just fine, but apparently stops working above 20px.

This only happens on Chrome, and only happens on my newer iMac. My older 27-inch iMac doesn't have this display problem, or any of my other Apple devices with Catalina and Chrome. So maybe it has something to do with the 5k display? Unclear.

My Chrome version is current, as of this writing it's Version 81.0.4044.113.

**Edit:**

Some additional digging:

- If I manually specify "SF Pro Text" or "SF Pro Display" for the `font-family`, it renders correctly with the right weights.
- [This Chromium bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1012247) seems very relevant, which links out to a section of [Apple's developer guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/visual-design/typography/) which would explain why it's changing at exactly 20px - because that's when the system tries to use SF Pro Display instead of SF Pro Text. Maybe that indicates an issue with the internally installed versions of these fonts:

> Use SF Pro Text for text 19 points or smaller, and SF Pro Display for text 20 points or larger. When you use San Francisco for text in standard controls like buttons and labels, macOS automatically applies the most appropriate variant based on the point size and the user’s accessibility settings.

- A [related chromium bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1005969) which describes the problem as related to kerning / tracking. It's closed, and makes no mention of font weight, but seems like the root cause might be the same.

Comment: I too am experiencing this.

Answer (score 2):

Found the correct chromium bug. As of this writing still open but hopefully will be fixed soon: [Issue 1057654](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1057654&q=component%3ABlink%3EFonts%20system-ui%20macos&can=2)

Comment: This is unconscionable on Chrome's part. How did a known bug like this make its way to the Chrome 81 release? Unbelievable. This makes me deeply untrustworthy of the stability of using the system font on any web project.

Comment: Read through the thread in the Chromium issue, the underlying problem is way more complex than it seems.